# How to get Multiple Enumerator on same Collection of objects?

Tags: c#, iterator

I have a collection of Partner objects in class PartnersPool i.e. List partners. I also have Entity objects. Each entity object contains "Sheet" which contains Partners list which in turn is being read from PartnerPool.

I want to enumerate over the partners in ParnerPool and get a enumerator back so that I could start from where I left for that particular entity.Different entities would enumerate over PartnerPool and each entity has it's own enumerator. I do not want to create the Partner Pool multiple time to get multiple enumerator.

So I want to do the following. Assume I have 100 partners:

```
//Create a Enumerator.
var Enumerator<Partner> enumeratorForEntity1;
//Create first entity 
var entity1 = new entity();
//following call gets only first 30 patners.
sheet.PartnerList = PartnerPool.GetOnlyThirtyPartnerDataAndReturnEnumerator(out Enumerator<Partner> enumeratorForEntity1 );
//Now create entity2 and enumerator for it.
var Enumerator<Partner> enumeratorForEntity2;
var entity2 = new entity();
//following method call should return the first 30 partners also.
//that is it should return brand new enumerator.
sheet.PartnerList = PartnerPool.GetOnlyThirtyPartnerDataAndReturnEnumerator(out Enumerator<Partner> enumeratorForEntity2 );

//Now if I again use the first enumerator i.e. "enumeratorForEntity1" I should get the next 30 partners that is, from 30 to 60.
sheet.PartnerList = PartnerPool.GetOnlyThirtyPartnerDataAndReturnEnumerator(out Enumerator<Partner> enumeratorForEntity1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In class PartnerPool, it's better if you have 2 separate methods:

```
public List<Partner> GetOnlyThirtyPartnerDataAndReturnEnumerator(out Enumerator<Partner> enumerator) { /*Do whatever you are doing right now*/ }
public List<Partner> GetNextThirtyPartnerData(Enumerator<Partner> enumerator) { /*Use the enumerator to continue looping on the list*/ }
```

On the 2nd method, just call enumerator.MoveNext, get enumerator.Current then add to the returned list

Comment: Well, 30 was an example, number of partners would be dynamically generated based on certain condition.